# from . import (constants, error, message, context, ImportError: cannot import name 'constants'

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, path

I'm a beginner and have been stuck on this problem a few days now. This is on Windows 10 with python 3.6

MAIN PROBLEM:

> File "C:\Python 3.6\Lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython__init__.py",
>   line 6, in 
>       from . import (constants, error, message, context,
>  ImportError: cannot import name 'constants'

I'm trying to build a little app and running it in the command prompt to check it for errors and immediately I got an ImportError with

```
from ipywidgets import *
```

Even after setting the PATH variable correctly it still wasn't finding ipywidgets. When I used the command prompt as an interpretor it imported ipywidgets without a problem, it's only when I run the script that it doesn't.

So I added to the code

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\Python 3.6\Lib\site-packages')
```

which is where the ipywidgets module is located and it is now giving me

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Python
>   3.6\Scripts\SQLapp.py", line 5, in 
>       from ipywidgets import Text
>    File "C:\Python 3.6\Lib\site-packages\ipywidgets__init__.py", line 25, in 
>       from .widgets import *
>    File "C:\Python 3.6\Lib\site-packages\ipywidgets\widgets__init__.py", line 4, in 
>       from .widget import Widget, CallbackDispatcher, register, widget_serialization
>    File "C:\Python
>   3.6\Lib\site-packages\ipywidgets\widgets\widget.py", line 13, in 
>       from ipykernel.comm import Comm
>    File "C:\Python 3.6\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel__init__.py", line 2, in 
>       from .connect import *
>    File "C:\Python 3.6\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in 
>       import jupyter_client
>    File "C:\Python 3.6\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client__init__.py", line 4, in 
>       from .connect import *
>    File "C:\Python 3.6\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 22, in 
>       import zmq
>    File "C:\Python 3.6\Lib\site-packages\zmq__init__.py", line 34, in 
>       from zmq import backend
>    File "C:\Python 3.6\Lib\site-packages\zmq\backend__init__.py", line 40, in 
>       reraise(*exc_info)
>    File "C:\Python 3.6\Lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
>       raise value
>    File "C:\Python 3.6\Lib\site-packages\zmq\backend__init__.py", line 27, in 
>       _ns = select_backend(first)
>    File "C:\Python 3.6\Lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 26, in select_backend
>       mod = **import**(name, fromlist=public_api)
>    File "C:\Python 3.6\Lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython__init__.py", line 6, in 
>       from . import (constants, error, message, context,
>  ImportError: cannot import name 'constants'

I've uninstalled pyzmq, zmq and installed both again, it didn't help.

I've looked up several posts with the same problem and while just about everyone of them had figured out a solution, they didn't mention their specific steps. I've pretty much reached the limits of my python software knowledge and google searching skills.

EDIT:
with a little script called pathtest.py I found the paths which are these:

> C:\Python 3.6\Scripts
>  C:\Python 3.6
>  C:\Python
>   3.6\Scripts
>  C:\Python 3.6\libs
>  C:\Python 3.6\Lib
>  C:\Python 3.6\Lib\site-packages
>  C:\Users\Sten den
>   Bakker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python36.zip
>   C:\Users\Sten den
>   Bakker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs
>  C:\Users\Sten
>   den Bakker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib
>   C:\Users\Sten den Bakker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36
>   C:\Users\Sten den
>   Bakker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages

It seems I have python installed twice, only the above folder having the ipywidgets library. I think it might very well be the problem. Any idea on how to remove the last few folders from the path?

Thanks for reading,
Minime

EDIT:
Solved it. It was indeed happening because of the multiple versions of python.